# Replace static json data in handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I'm doing some maintenance on a project I haven't worked with before that uses .hbs files for templating and a static json file for initial data. The javascript appears to be vanilla (no backbone.js, Angular, etc.)

Is there a "correct" way of overwriting the data in that file after I get a JSON object from a REST call AFTER the page loads?

This is what is in the .hbs file:

```
{{> dropdown-module platform-demos.registerDemoType }}
```

This is what is in the static JSON file:

```
"registerDemoType": {
    "label": "Demo Type",
    "placeholder": "Choose Demo",
    "inverted": "inverted",
    "id": "demoId",
    "items": [{
      "option": "Basic Demo",
      "optionValue": "basic-demo-dp"
    }, {
      "option": "Intermediate Demo",
      "optionValue": "intermediate-demo-dp"
    }, {
      "option": "Advanced Demo",
      "optionValue": "advanced-demo-dp"
    }]
  }
```

And then my REST call pulls back data similar to that:

```
"demoTypes": [{
          "option": "New Demo 1",
          "optionValue": "basic-demo-dp"
        }, {
          "option": "New Demo 2",
          "optionValue": "intermediate-demo-dp"
        }, {
          "option": "New Demo 3",
          "optionValue": "advanced-demo-dp"
        }]
```

Is there a "correct" way of replacing the static data with the REST call data?

Comment: Are you trying to replace registerDemoType.items with 'demoTypes'? Or are you trying to add the 'demoTypes' to the registerDemoType.items?

Comment: Replace the current list items with 'demoTypes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how handlebars works. Handlebars does not have any form of data binding built into it so you cannot simply change the values that were passed in and have the rendered HTML change automatically.

Instead, when your REST call is complete, you will have to update the object you are passing into your template as Hoyen suggested

```
registerDemoType.items = demoTypes;
```

And then you have to re-render this handlebars template, passing in `registerDemoType` as your data.

**In short:** You cannot access the hbs data after it has been rendered, you must re-render.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I didn't understand about handlebars. I thought it was similar to angular, instead, it's closer to PHP or JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace it. Then all you should really need to do is something like this after the REST call responds:

```
registerDemoType.items = demoTypes;
```

Comment: Will "registerDemoType" be an accessible variable in the external javascript file?

Comment: As long as after you read in the file, you can store the data into a JavaScript variable where your external JavaScript file can access.

Comment: So I guess the real question is, how do I make that hbs data available as a global?

Comment: If the handlebars template can access 'platform-demos.registerDemoType'. Then you should be able to access it too?

Comment: I tried: console.log(Object["platform-demos"]); but got an undefined value

Comment: I'm not sure how your app works. So, without looking at the entire code base. I won't be able to really help you any further than what you have provided.